# jQuery.on use with parent and child selectors vs just child selector

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 2.0.3

Is there any difference between:

```
$(parentSelector).on("click", childSelector, function() {...});
```

and

```
$(childSelector).on("click", function() {...});
```

Why would I ever want to use the former instead of the latter?

Comment: The second is identical to `$(sel).click(function() {...}`; it doesn't employ the primary purpose of `on()`, event delegation. See the answer by ROX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is called **event delegation**, if your `childSelector` elements added to DOM **later**,

- the first one will work (new added elements have event handlers) - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pvxpadv/1/).
- but the second one won't (new added elements doesn't have any event handler) - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pvxpadv/).

Comment: Thanks for the examples - they made it easier to understand!

Answer (score 1):

Example code from the [jQuery's .on() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

Consider a table with 1000 rows.  The following attaches a handler to 1000 elements:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

This will work, but if we add rows, we'd have attach the event handler again.

With the delegated approach, the event handler is only attached to the `tbody`, and the event only has to bubble up from the `tr` to the `tbody`:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks Timothy - I somehow missed that example. It does clarify the difference as well.